# How to match strings in two files and replace strings?

Tags: awk

I have a file like this: (has 308545 lines)

```
head output11.frq
 CHR               SNP   A1   A2          MAF  NCHROBS
   1      1:775852:T:C    T    C       0.1707     3444
   1     1:1120590:A:C    C    A      0.08753     3496
   1     1:1145994:T:C    C    T       0.1765     3496
   1     1:1148494:A:G    A    G       0.1059     3464
   1     1:1201155:C:T    T    C      0.07923     3496
...
```

And another file (marker-info) which has the first 24 commented lines and is comma separated that looks like this (has total of 500593 lines):

```
1,742429,SNP_A-1909444,ss66079302,rs3094315,36.2,G,A,C,T,A,GCACAGCAAGAGAAAC[A/G]TTTGACAGAGAATACA,Sty,+,-,y,,,127,phs000018
1,769185,SNP_A-4303947,ss66273559,rs4040617,36.2,A,G,A,G,A,GCTGTGAGAGAGAACA[A/G]TGTCCCAATTTTGCCC,Sty,+,+,n,,,127,phs000018
1,775852,SNP_A-1886933,ss66317030,rs2980300,36.2,T,C,A,G,A,GAATGACTGTGTCTCT[C/T]TGAGTTAGTGAAGTCA,Nsp,-,+,y,,,127,phs000018
1,782343,SNP_A-2236359,ss66185183,rs2905036,36.2,C,T,C,T,A,CTCGATTTGTGTTCAA[C/T]ATATTTCATTTGTACC,Sty,-,-,n,,,127,phs000018
1,1201155,SNP_A-2205441,ss66174584,rs4245756,36.2,C,T,C,T,A,CCAGTGCTTTCAACCA[C/T]ACTCACTTTTCACTGT,Sty,+,+,n,,,127,phs000018
...
```

I want to replace in output11.frq second column with the 5th column in marker-info that has the matching value in 1st and 2nd column so for this example the result of the output11.frq would look like this:

```
1      rs2980300    T    C       0.1707     3444
1      rs4245756    T    C      0.07923     3496
```

I tried doing this but I got empty file:

```
vi tst.awk
NR==FNR { map[$1,$2]=$5; next }
($1,$4) in map { $2=map[$1,$4]; print }


awk -f tst.awk FS=',' marker-info FS='\t' output11.frq  > output11X.frq
```

EDIT:

I tried to run this:

```
 vi test2.awk
 NR==FNR { map[$2]=$5 }
 NR!=FNR { split($4, x, ":"); if(x[2] in map){ $4=map[x[2]]; print }}

awk -f test2.awk FS=',' marker-info FS='\t' output11.frq > output11X.frq
```

but I got this:

```
head output11X.frq
 CHR               SNP   A1   A2          MAF  NCHROBS   rs41340551
   1      1:775852:T:C    T    C       0.1707     3444   rs41340551
   1     1:1120590:A:C    C    A      0.08753     3496   rs41340551
   1     1:1145994:T:C    C    T       0.1765     3496   rs41340551
...
```

Comment: Plese [edit] your question and show the complete expected output that should result from the example input files in your question. The technique in your `awk` script requires that you specify at least two files on the command line. The first file is read to fill `map` and all other files will be processed using `map`. If you specify one file only you won't get any output. Please explain in your question what you think are the values in the relevant columns `$1`, `$2`, `$5`, `$4` in your example input. The values in the two files don't seem to match without further processing.

Comment: Thank you so much, I edited it!

Comment: Please explain in your question why the expected output has only 2 lines? and how exactly the data is expected to match. A difficulty is that the two files have different field separators. As I understand the files, in `output11.frq` column 1 is `1` and column 2 is `1:775852:T:C`. In the other file column 1 is `1` and column 2 is `742429`. This will never match without further processing. It is unclear which values `1` in the two files must match because `output11.frq` has a `1` in two places.

Comment: two lines is just for this snippet of data shown here which can be used to test code. I only need to match by position here 775852

Comment: Please add all information to the question. Your comment does not explain how exactly the data must match. I suggest to add some debug output to the `awk` script, e.g. `NR==FNR { map[$1,$2]=$5; printf "$1=%s, $2=%s, $5=%s\n", $1, $2, $5; next }`. If this doesn't make some errors obvious, show the resulting output in the question.

Comment: the this is that I am getting an empty file when I run the command I shown above. So for this concrete line in the example output I have in output11.frq 1:775852:T:C and I am looking to find 775852 in the 2nd column of the marker-info and if I have that I am matching 1 from 1:775852 in the same matched line in marker-info. I think it is sufficient just to match 775852, 1 is not even needed, and when that is matched replace 1:775852:T:C with rs2980300 in output11.frq

Comment: You may need to adjust your fields based on how many tabs are in output.frq. Instead of `$4`, try `$3` or `$5`. If you're not sure what they are, add a `print` statement to help you determine which field is which. Your output suggests some of the tabs might actually be other whitespace characters.

Comment: I've updated my answer to recommend using `FS=' '` and the `$2` field. This should prevent issues with tab-based field numbering.

Comment: @anamaria **Please [edit] your question and add all information there.** All information related to your problem should be **in the question** and not scattered over comments. Comments are for suggestions or to ask for clarification or missing information.

Comment: Hi I did put EDIT in my post, please see above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your script was that you were trying to use strings like `11:775852:T:C` as keys in a map whose keys are of the format `775852`.

I have omitted the first column from this processing since you mentioned in a comment that you don't think it's needed.

```c
NR==FNR { map[$2]=$5 }
NR!=FNR { split($2, x, ":"); if(x[2] in map){ $2=map[x[2]]; print }}
```

I used `split` to obtain the relevant part of the string and added a conditional since until that substring is processed, there's no way to perform the lookup you need.

This appears to perform as requested:

```bsh
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/dna]$ awk -f test.awk FS=',' marker-info FS=' ' output11.frq
 1  rs2980300 T C 0.1707 3444
 1  rs4245756 T C 0.07923 3496
```

Make sure the fields you have line up with the columns you think you have. If you'd like the output to be tab-delimited, you can set the `OFS` variable in the second half of the script, like so: `NR!=FNR { OFS="\t"; split($2, x, ":"); if(x[2] in map){ $2=map[x[2]]; print }}`

EDIT: I have changed the `FS` variable in the command to change the delimiter for output11.frq to whitespace. This will prevent fiddliness with number of tabs.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I did run what you wrote above and this is what I got:

Comment: I will put in my post the output, under EDIT

Comment: This worked wonderfully! Thank you so much!